# Fetching data from MS SQL Server 2008 to Oracle via ODBC: Getting ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 error

Tags: oracle10g, odbc

Background:

I am fetching data from a database on SQL Server 2008 (`SQLA` ) over to Oracle (`ORCLA`) . The data is pulled using a database link, via HS ODBC connection. Both the SQL and Oracle databases were 32-bit editions.

Now, we moved the Oracle database onto faster 64-bit servers(`ORCLB`), the 32-bit Oracle database remained on the older system, and this system (`ORCLA`) was still used as the "gateway" between the 2 databases. Today, the 32-bit Oracle server (`ORCLA`) was scrapped.

This broke interface between the 2. I tried to setup the HS ODBC connection on the 64-bit Oracle server (`ORCLB`) I started getting the above error message. Upon further researching
I found that the HS ODBC gateway is not supported on a 64-bit system. So I setup the HS ODBC connection on another 32-bit Oracle server(`ORCLC`) that we have. The HS ODBC setup ( listeners, et al) on 64-bit server (`ORCLB`) were scrapped.

Problem:
 I can ping `SQLA`, using `tnsping`. `lsnrctl` shows that listNer is correct.
I can connect to a database on `ORCLC` and fetch data from `SQLA`. However, while trying to fetch data from `SQLA` onto `ORCLB` results in the above error message being thrown. 
I have no idea what I can do to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

The 32-bit systems use Oracle 10gR2, the 64-bit edition uses Oracle 10.2.0.4.

(Pardon me if I posted incorrectly here, I felt this is more of a server side issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke my head trying to get this working and I got so frustrated with ORA-28545 errors I just gave up.

Setup a 32-bit Oracle installation on a standalone PC to speak to SQL Server and used a dblink from the 64-bit Oracle server to the 32-bit Oracle stand alone PC. Long winded approach ? Yeah but no more digging across logs trying to find why and where the connection is breaking down.